# Pyside - QcolorDialog signals

Tags: python, pyside, qt-signals, qcolor, qcolordialog

What would be the signal for clicking the 'ok' button in the QColorDialog.

I tried

```
self.color_chooser = QtWidgets.QColorDialog()
self.color_chooser.getColor()
self.color_chooser.currentColorChanged.connect(self.color_pick)

def color_pick(self):
    print 'signaled'
```

that did not work.

Comment: pyside or pyside2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal you are requesting is `colorSelected`, this is issued after pressing the OK button

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.color_chooser = QColorDialog()
        self.color_chooser.colorSelected.connect(self.color_pick)
        self.color_chooser.show()

    def color_pick(self, color):
        print('signaled', color)
```

If you want to get the color after pressing the OK button you can use these other methods:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.color_chooser = QColorDialog()
        if self.color_chooser.exec_() == QColorDialog.Accepted:
            print(self.color_chooser.currentColor())
```

---

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.color_chooser = QColorDialog()
        color = self.color_chooser.getColor()
        if color.isValid():
            print(color, color.name())
```